# How can I add two classes to an element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-4">
<%= check_box("terms", "validated") %>
<strong>foobar </strong><%= link_to "darwin", "#"%>
      </div>
      </div>
<div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-3">
      <%= f.submit "Create my account", :class => "btn btn-lg btn-primary", disabled: "disabled" %>
      </div>
      </div>
```

I'm able to add a class to an element, but I want to add two classes to my button element. I want to add the "form-control" class to it. How can do this? Thank you.

Comment: change `:class => "btn btn-lg btn-primary"` to `:class => "btn btn-lg btn-primary form-control"`

Comment: I would post this as an answer and you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
:class => "btn btn-lg btn-primary"
```

to

```
:class => "btn btn-lg btn-primary form-control"
```